# Value not setting in pandas dataframe while iterating

Tags: python, pandas

I have a counter that looks like this:

```
Counter({'.java': 57,
         'python': 1159,
         'c++': 167,
         'c#': 20})
```

And a dataframe like this:

```
languages = ['java', 'python', 'c++', 'c#']
df = pd.DataFrame(index= languages, columns = ['count'])
df['count'] = df['count'].fillna(0)
```

I'd like to iterate over the counter so that the values in the dataframe update:

```
for language in languages:
    df.loc[language, 'count'] = ctr[language]
```

But I get 0 for the value in the whole dataframe:

```
        count
java    0
python  0
c++     0
c#      0
```

This happens even when I set `df.loc[language, 'count'] = 9` or any other number.

Why is this happening? This is how I've always iterated over dataframes and set values.

Comment: For me it working nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the most embarrassing answer I've had to post to my own question, and while I kind of wish that SO would let me delete the whole thing (it won't now that others have answered), another part of me is glad that it is making me A) face my own shame, and B) post an answer that I think is instructive in how to write clean code.

In my question, I used the fake variable `df`, both to adhere to a standard and to obscure the names I used. So my question looked like:

```
languages = ['java', 'python', 'c++', 'c#']
df = pd.DataFrame(index= languages, columns = ['count'])
df['count'] = df['count'].fillna(0)

for language in languages:
    df.loc[language, 'count'] = ctr[language]
```

But what was actually happening in my notebook looked like this:

```
languages = ['java', 'python', 'c++', 'c#']
jobs_count_df = pd.DataFrame(index= languages, columns = ['count'])
jobs_count_df['count'] = jobs_count_df['count'].fillna(0)

for language in languages:
    jobs_df.loc[language, 'count'] = 1
```

Now that the sun is out and I'm not fighting sleep, it's not hard to see what the problem was. But in a bleary-eyed, late-night session (not an uncommon environment in which to be coding), I overlooked that I was iterating over a different but *stupidly, similarly named* variable. I feel like it's common, especially among people like me who are not extremely seasoned, to write sloppy variable names (`df`, `df2`, etc.) that all but beg for mistakes like this. I've learned my lesson the hard way (i.e., by embarrassing myself).

Thanks to those who wrote answers. You're upvoted for dealing with my idiocy.

Answer (score 1):

Usually it should work if not you have to convert the Counter to dictionary. then it'll work.

```
languages = ['java', 'python', 'c++', 'c#']
df = pd.DataFrame(index= languages, columns = ['count'])
df['count'] = df['count'].fillna(0)
dctr = dict(ctr)
dctr = {'java': 57,
         'python': 1159,
         'c++': 167,
         'c#': 20}
for language in languages:
    df.loc[language, 'count'] = dctr[language]

print(df)


        count
java       57
python   1159
c++       167
c#         20
```

PS: Above @jezrael answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: When I run it, OP's code executes without error, without converting `Counter` to `dict`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `Counter` to [`DataFrame.from_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html):

```
ctr = Counter({'java': 57,
         'python': 1159,
         'c++': 167,
         'c#': 20})

#pandas 0.23.0
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ctr, orient='index', columns=['count'])

#lower versions of pandas
#df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ctr, orient='index')
#df.columns=['count']
print (df)

        count
java       57
python   1159
c++       167
c#         20
```

If list `languages` have more values like in `Counter` add [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
languages = ['java', 'python', 'c++', 'c#', 'perl']

df = df.reindex(languages, fill_value=0)
print (df)
        count
java       57
python   1159
c++       167
c#         20
perl        0
```

Comment: Hello sir, this is Awesome !!

Comment: @jezrael, you initialized languages but where are you using it?

Comment: @pyd - no, there are languages set from keys of Counter. But good point, answer will be edited - if more keys in list like in `Counter`

Comment: @jezrael I am getting `TypeError: from_dict() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'` is it because of lower version of pandas ?

Comment: @pyd - yes, if check http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html it is new in `pandas 0.23.0`

Comment: @pyd - Thank you for comments, added code for version bellow `0.23.0`